# Hacer login en NodeJS con passport-local-mongoose al crear un usuario automaticamente

Tags: nodejs

He creado una ruta "/register" que en vez de que saque un formulario para que el usuario se registre, lo hace automáticamente, es decir, genera un nombre de usuario y un password y almacena el usuario en la coleción.

Lo que quiero es que ese usuario que acabo de crear se loguee automaticamente una vez registrado pero no llego a comprender como hacerlo.

Aquí tengo mi código.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");
const User = require("./user.model");

//Database conection
const connection = mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://*******:*******@cluster0.mzwtw.mongodb.net/**********?retryWrites=true&w=majority", (err) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Connection established");
    }
})

//Middleware para poder obtener datos post del form
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//Configure express-session
app.use(require("express-session")({
    "secret": "my secret",
    "resave": false,
    "saveUninitialized": false
}))

//configure passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    
    User.register(new User( { username: "user-aleatorio" }), "mypassword", (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        if (!err)
        {
            console.log("User registered");
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                res.redirect("/secret");
            });

            console.log("Autenticado: " + req.isAuthenticated());
        }
    })
})

app.listen(3001, () => { 
    console.log("App escuchando en el puerto 3001")
});
```

He visto algunos ejemplos y cuando ponían passport.authenticate se logueaba el usuario, pero entiendo que es porque passport examina los datos pasados por post y encuentra el username y password. He intentado hacer un

```
req.body.username = "user-aleatorio";
req.body.password = "mypassword";
```

antes del passport.authenticate pero nada.

Agradezco vuestros comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación de Passport deberías utilizar el método `req.login` en vez de
`passport.authenticate`. http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/

```
console.log("User registered");

req.login(user, (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Autenticado: " + req.isAuthenticated());
    return res.redirect("/secret");
  }
});

console.log("Autenticado: " + req.isAuthenticated());
```

Comment: Que grande! Eso me pasa por no leer la documentación oficial. Muchas gracias.